# Validation accuracy of deep learning model is stuck at 0.5 whereas training accuracy is improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

My TF deep learning model is stuck at validation accuracy of 50% whereas my training accuracy is at 65% and increasing. Following are some points to note-

1. Problem statement - I am using (224*224) faces as input and trying to predict gender
2. Data Size - I have 29,999 images each for Male and female. training data is 80% - 47,998, Validation data is 20% - 11,999
3. Below is my code. It might be a bit overwhelming, feel free to ask me specific questions -

   ```
   def generator(positive_dataset, negative_dataset):
   while True:
       for pos_rec, neg_rec in zip(positive_dataset, negative_dataset):
             pos_x, pos_y = pos_rec
             neg_x, neg_y = neg_rec
             x = tf.concat([pos_x, neg_x], axis=0)
             y = tf.concat([pos_y, neg_y], axis=0)
             yield x, y
   train_generator = generator(train_dataset_female, train_dataset_male) 
   test_generator = generator(test_dataset_female, test_dataset_male)
   input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
   mobilenet_layer = MobileNetV2(weights=None, include_top=False, alpha=0.35)(input_layer)
   landmarks_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mobilenet_layer)
   landmarks_layer = layers.Flatten()(landmarks_layer)
   landmarks_layer_flat = layers.Dense(68 * 2, activation='sigmoid', name='landmarks_flat')(landmarks_layer)
   landmarks_layer = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(68, 2), name='landmarks')(landmarks_layer_flat)

   landmarks_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=landmarks_layer)

   prob_face_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mobilenet_layer)
   prob_face_layer = layers.Flatten()(prob_face_layer)
   prob_face_layer = layers.concatenate([prob_face_layer, landmarks_layer_flat])
   prob_face_layer = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(prob_face_layer)
   prob_face_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(prob_face_layer)

   prob_face_net = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=prob_face_layer)
   print('Prob Face Net')
   print(prob_face_net.summary())

   print('Pose Model')
   pose_model.summary()

   print('Landmarks Model')
   landmarks_model.summary()

   combined_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs[landmarks_layer, pose_layer])
   print('Combined Model')
   combined_model.summary()

   full_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[prob_face_layer, landmarks_layer, pose_layer])
   print('Full Net')
   print(full_model.summary())


   combined_model.load_weights('/mnt/sachins/apprach2/models/bounding_box_based_model_faster_2.h5')
   for layer in range(0, 8):
       prob_face_net.layers[layer].trainable = False 
   prob_face_net.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[ 'accuracy'])


   history = prob_face_net.fit_generator(
               train_generator,
               epochs=EPOCHS,
               steps_per_epoch=(num_train_imgs_male+ num_train_imgs_female)//(BATCH_SIZE//2),
               validation_data=test_generator,
               validation_steps=(29999*2 - (num_train_imgs_male+num_train_imgs_female))//(BATCH_SIZE//2),
               callbacks=callbacks,
               verbose = 1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should think about ethical problems of your model. https://venturebeat.com/2020/02/20/google-cloud-ai-removes-gender-labels-from-cloud-vision-api-to-avoid-bias/

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out. Just to clear things up, Iam doing this as a practice problem. Would be nice to get your help on the problem Iam facing.